# Jquery combine code

Tags: jquery

Sorry for the really simple question but how could I combine below Jquery ?
The question is how can I set :

```
 $('.cmb2 OR .cmb3 OR .cmb4').hover(function () 
 $('.cm2 OR .cm3 OR .cm4 DEPENDS ON WHAT IS HOVERED IN ABOVE LINE ').addClass('cmactive');
```

COMPLETE CODE :

```
 $('.cmb2').hover(function ()
 {
 $('.cmactive').hide();
 $('.cmactive').removeClass('cmactive');
 $('.cm2').addClass('cmactive');
 $('.cm2').show();
 });

$('.cmb3').hover(function ()
{
$('.cmactive').hide();
$('.cmactive').removeClass('cmactive');
$('.cm3').addClass('cmactive');
$('.cm3').show();
});

$('.cmb4').hover(function ()
{
$('.cmactive').hide();
$('.cmactive').removeClass('cmactive');
$('.cm4').addClass('cmactive');
$('.cm4').show();
});
```

Comment: Im sorry guys, I made a typo. Thanks for all the examples but I already was aware of this but the problem is I need to change an other class and not the class hovered. :( so hover .cmb1 change .someotherclass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the comma combinator to combine selectors:

```
$('.cmb2,.cmb3,.cmb4').hover(function ()
```

In the event handler the context (`this`) is the element where the event was triggered, so you can check the class of that element to find out what element to show.

```
$('.cmb2,.cmb3,.cmb4').hover(function () {
  $('.cmactive').hide().removeClass('cmactive');
  var target =
    $(this).hasClass('cmb2') ? '.cm2' :
    $(this).hasClass('cmb3') ? '.cm3' :
    '.cm4';
  $(target).addClass('cmactive').show();
});
```

Comment: Your function works perfect, would you be so kind to explain me the : ? '.cm3' :
    '.cm4'; the first .cm2 I understand.

Comment: @BRDS: It's using the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to select a value. The same as `var target; if ($(this).hasClass('cmb2')) { target = '.cm2'; } else if ($(this).hasClass('cmb3')) { target = '.cm3'; } else { target = '.cm4'; }`

Comment: Got it, did not understand the ? part.

Answer (score 1):

Use commas to have a list of selectors, and if you assign it to a variable you can do work against all of them in the callback function.

```
var $cmbs = $('.cmb2, .cmb3, .cmb4');

$cmbs.hover(function () 
    $(this).addClass('cmactive');
    $cmbs.not(this).removeClass('cmactive');
});
```

Comment: Im sorry, I made a typo. Thanks for all the examples but I already was aware of this but the problem is I need to change an other class and not the class hovered. :( so hover .cmb1 change .someotherclass

Comment: Have you thought about moving the targetting logic to the HTML? `<div class='cmb1' data-target='.cm1'>`, and having your function use that: `var target = $(this).data('target')`?

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a common class to all three of them and then queue off of that? Alternatively you can use a CSS selector like this: `$('[class^="cmb"]')`.  You can also select multiple classes by separating what you want with a comma, so you could do `$('.cmb2, .cmb3, .cmb4')`